# JavaScript file not showing in Rails assets file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[image: VSCODE screen shot]

Can anyone tell me why JavaScript file not showing on rails application? Sorry I'm beginner to rails.

Looking for solution why Assets not showing JavaScript file.

Answer (score 0):

By default there isn't "javascript" folder in "assets".

Comment: How can I add. Are there any resources? Thanks for your reply

Comment: I added gem 'webpacker' , github: 'rails/webpacker' to my gem file. Then I run bundle and lastly run rails webpacker:install.

Comment: Now I'm getting "$ rails webpacker:install
Warning: you are using an unstable release of Node.js (v19.1.0). If you encounter issues with Node.js, consider switching to an Active LTS release. More info: https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-node
"

Comment: I have latest node Js version which is v19.1.0. Can you tell me what can be the wrong

Comment: No I changed nvm version to lts version and run above command. Now getting different error and It says "$ rails webpacker:install
C:\Ruby31-x64\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- F:/Rails (LoadError)"